# Things/any reference to consider for safety to use the voltage ADC info from 3 IGBT bridges in the control loop?

Tags: motor, adc, inverter, control-system, igbt

[image]

Is there any mode apart from the short circuit and normal mode, that I need to check for the control loop to be executed by the micro controller?

Comment: Your diagram is wrong. Leg-C doesn't have an output while leg-B has 2

Comment: @JonRB, Thank you, my reference was wrong and I have it corrected now.

Comment: You should be monitoring the voltage at the midpoint of the capacitive divider if you want to avoid problems with any other circuits sharing the bus. Circulating currents can waste a lot of energy. Make sure your IGBT driver has some desaturation protection too. IGBTs are finicky.

Comment: @Hearth, Thank you for the time to look at this and provide insight, so is it not feasible to check the status of the IGBTs switches?, Idea is to know the states of each switch from the feedback and determine/ensure the mode of operation as intended.

Comment: What "status" do you want to check? No fault condition could be corrected fast enough by a microcontroller; that's why you use drivers with built in protection circuitry to shut things down in the event of a fault, and *those* can signal to the microcontroller that something's wrong. For IGBTs you want desaturation protection at minimum, and a Miller clamp would certainly not hurt; these are features most IGBT drivers should have. They would also have logic outputs to signal fault conditions to the controller, upon which it can take whatever action you deem necessary.

Comment: @Hearth, Thanks for the reply, by "status" I intend to know  how to reach about safe states in a drive. My reference is this paper "https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2017186436A1/en". This is the main content over there.I am assuming they use the same bridge circuit configuration to check for active short circuit as explained in this.